# How to change the sqlite db storage in internal memory

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created an android application for off line concept. when internet connected data can be sync through server.

My tablet pc has more than 5.7GB storage space as internal memory. when I sync data from the server, its reporting an error as out of memory.

I think data storage location is changed, its storing some where else. Can anyone resolve this problem? I think some modification to be made in manifest file.

#### My sync code

```
public class sync extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static String url = "Json URL";
// Button
Button chktosync, logout_menu;
private ProgressDialog pd;
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
JSONArray contacts = null;
JSONArray cropdetails = null;
JSONArray biodetails = null;
String land, area, sf, land_id;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sync);
    logout_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout_menu);
    logout_menu.setOnClickListener(this);
    chktosync = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chktosync);
    chktosync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(sync.this, "Synchronizing", "Synchronizing...");
        new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        try {
            processThread();
            pestanddisease();
            bioparam();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        // dismiss the progress dialog
    pd.dismiss();
}
        }.start();
    }
    });
}
private void processThread() {

// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    contacts = json.getJSONArray(loginPage.code);
    db.open();
    // looping through All Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    // Storing each json item in variable
    String farmerid = c.getString("farmerid");
    String farmername = c.getString("farmername");
    String farmer_fathername = c.getString("farmer_fathername");
    String farmer_mobilenumber = c.getString("farmer_mobilenumber");
    String districtname = c.getString("districtname");
    String blockname = c.getString("blockname");
    String villagename = c.getString("villagename");

    db.insertFarmer(farmerid, farmername,
            farmer_fathername, farmer_mobilenumber,
            districtname, blockname, villagename);
    //land details
    JSONArray Land = c.getJSONArray("land_details");
            for (int l = 0; l < Land.length(); l++) {
        JSONObject s = Land.getJSONObject(l);
        String survey_no = s.getString("survey_no");
        String area  = s.getString("area");
        String land_type = s.getString("land_type");
        String patternref = s.getString("patternref");
        String crop_matrix_id = s.getString("crop_matrix");
        land_id = s.getString("land_id");
        String season1_crop = s.getString("season1_crop");
        String season2_crop = s.getString("season2_crop");
        String season3_crop = s.getString("season3_crop");
        db.insertlanddetails(farmerid, survey_no, area, land_type, patternref, land_id, crop_matrix_id, season1_crop, season2_crop, season3_crop);
}
db.close();
  } 
catch (JSONException e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
}


   public void pestanddisease()
     {
         /// Creating JSON Parser instance
         JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(pestdisease);
    try    
    {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    cropdetails = json.getJSONArray("CropDetails");
    db.open();
    for (int i = 0; i < cropdetails.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject s = cropdetails.getJSONObject(i);
    String cropname = s.getString("crop");
    String pest = s.getString("pest_name");
    String disease = s.getString("disease_name");
    db.insertcrop_pest_details(cropname, pest);
    db.insertcrop_disease_details(cropname, disease);
}
    db.close();
 }      catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

#### JSONParser code

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),1048576);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            line=reader.readLine();
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
         Log.e("JSON", json);   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
    }
}
```

#### Log Cat

```
08-28 02:06:59.199: E/dalvikvm-heap(304): Out of memory on a 9513056-byte allocation.

08-28 02:06:59.446: E/AndroidRuntime(304): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:131)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:413)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.login.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:55)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.login.sync.processThread(sync.java:76)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.login.sync.access$1(sync.java:70)
08-28 02:06:59.732: E/AndroidRuntime(304): at com.login.sync$1$1.run(sync.java:57)
08-28 02:07:00.416: I/dalvikvm(304): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-28 02:07:00.416: E/dalvikvm(304): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Looks your problem is not caused by lack of storage. If you are getting an `OutOfMemoryError` exception, you will need to rework you network connection code to redirect `OutputStream` to file system but not in memory. Post you downloading sync code here would be more helpful.

Comment: post the logcat of the error you are getting too so that we can see the stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Sync is working fine but i can download only 156KB which means 1000 records from the server. If i try to fetch huge data its reports an error of OutOfMemory. I thought it was an error in manifest file. Please advice me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me in detail. where i have to integrate this code. how to insert the json data in local sqlite database tables.. Thanks in andvance.

Comment: you need to re-implement your `JSONObject.getJSONFromUrl(URL)` method. If it's from some 3rd-party lib, you will need to implement the pulling code by your self. The sample code I post below will retrieve JSON to file system, you read it by String and parse into JSON. Rest are the same.

Comment: JSONParser code also attached. Its working fine for 1000 records. Please explain in detail. If more than 1000 records i try download.Null pointer Exception occurs. More than 4 days i have been try to solve this problem. Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same code is working fine. My problem was JSON. JSON not coming properly. I did some modification on JSON. Now its working fine.More than 4000 records downloaded with out error.I think no need to change the file. Json parser is working fine. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json parser working fine. No need to change it into file. Reason for the error is JSON was not coming properly.I did some modification on server side. Now its working fine. Before synchronizing data please ensure that JSON is valid or not.Thanks for your support...

Answer (score 0):

So `OutOfMemoryError` doesn't mean you are running out of capacity of your file system, it means you are running out of memory that is holding your downloading buffer.

In your case, you will need to change your `JSONObject.getJSONFromUrl(URL)` to manage download buffer on file system but not memory. Here is the example:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
    if (resEntity == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity should not be null.");

    is = resEntity.getContent();
    if (is == null) return 0;

    // Create parent folder to avoid IOException
    if (!mBinaryFile.getParentFile().exists())
        mBinaryFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    fos = new FileOutputStream(mBinaryFile, mDownloadedLength!=0);

        byte[] tmp = new byte[8192];
        int bufLength;
        while((bufLength = is.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            fos.write(tmp, 0, bufLength);
        }

    return mBinaryFile.length();

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ServerConnectionException(R.string.error_network_error,
            "Download file "+mBinaryFile.getName()+" failed.", e);
} finally {
    Utils.closeStream(is);
    Utils.closeStream(fos);
}
```

In this case, only 8KB memory is needed, so you OOM problem could be solved. But you problem will be turned to how to read JSON data from file system. Just read data you needed piece by piece to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`, and release memory as soon as you done with it.